# Aggregate by selecting last element in postgres group by

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing object statistics in postges with the following columns:

- **id** integer
- **object_id** integer
- **timestamp** timestamp with time zone
- **dimension** character varying
- **value** integer

Note that it's using the entity-attribute-value (eav) pattern - entity is `object_id`, attribute is `dimension`, value is `value`.

A job runs nightly that collects values over six dimensions (specified by `dimension`) for each object (specified by `object_id`).

I'd like to build a reporting page that shows that most recent `value` for each `dimension` for each `product`. The query would look like this:

`select object_id, dimension, FIRST(value) from pt_reading group by product_id, dimension  order by product_id, dimension, timestamp desc;`

`FIRST` would pick the first `value` which is the one I'd like since I'm sorting by timestamp desc. Unfortunately FIRST is not a valid aggregator function.

What's the best design pattern to do this? I could always fallback to writing it in python, but it seems like something that could be handled by the database. Also, please chime in if there's a different design pattern I should be using to do this.

Comment: For some explanation you might be interested in [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct on (object_id, dimension)
    object_id,
    dimension,
    value
from pt_reading
order by object_id, dimension, "timestamp" desc;
```